# How to make webrtc video call work when devices are on different networks

Tags: twilio, webrtc, stun, turn, peer

hope this meets you well

I'm trying to add videocall feature to my app, both media streams are displayed when devices are connected to the same wifi but not when they are on different networks.

i was using google stun servers like this

```
const config = new TNSRTCConfiguration({
iceServers: [
    new TNSRTCIceServer(['stun:stun.l.google.com:19302']),
    new TNSRTCIceServer(['stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302']),
]
})
this.connection = new TNSRTCPeerConnection(config);
```

Now i use twilio stun-turn and my generated iceServer is something like this

```
{"accountSid":"A*c4c7***00d1d9a74df****045785af**",
"dateCreated":"2020-11-15T21:22:11.000Z",
"dateUpdated":"2020-11-15T21:22:11.000Z",

"iceServers":[{"url":"stun:global.stun.twilio.com:3478?transport=udp",
"urls":"stun:global.stun.twilio.com:3478?transport=udp"},{"url":"turn:global.turn.twilio.com:3478?transport=udp",
"username":"4fb786c964c33a3022239ae1af6ae5fa64525d5ce2355da261f23ac2fbaeef31",
"urls":"turn:global.turn.twilio.com:3478?transport=udp",
"credential":"qPHa627LqJbEVoC6rG2BWq2TggpuH2q78+JkVOycSps="},
{"url":"turn:global.turn.twilio.com:3478?transport=tcp",
"username":"4fb786c964c33a3022239ae1af6ae5fa64525d5ce2355da261f23ac2fbaeef31",
"urls":"turn:global.turn.twilio.com:3478?transport=tcp",
"credential":"qPHa627LqJbEVoC6rG2BWq2TggpuH2q78+JkVOycSps="},{"url":"turn:global.turn.twilio.com:443?transport=tcp",
"username":"4fb786c964c33a3022239ae1af6ae5fa64525d5ce2355da261f23ac2fbaeef31",
"urls":"turn:global.turn.twilio.com:443?transport=tcp",
"credential":"qPHa627LqJbEVoC6rG2BWq2TggpuH2q78+JkVOycSps="}],

"password":"qPHa6****JbEVoC6rG***q2T***uH2q78+Jk**ycSps=",
"ttl":"86400",
"username":"4fb786c964c33a3022239ae1af6ae5fa64525d5ce2355da261f23ac2fbaeef31"}
```

This is how i use it in my app

```
this.socket.on("twilio iceservers", token => {
        const config = new TNSRTCConfiguration({
            iceServers: token.iceServers
        })
        this.connection = new TNSRTCPeerConnection(config);
.
.
.
});
```

Please what could be the cause of this?

Comment: `Ice Servers` are used for this functionality which is the combination of `STUN` & `TURN` candidates. STUN servers are freely available but for the TURN server, you can either deploy [CoTURN Server](https://github.com/coturn/coturn) or you can simply use these vendors such as [Twilio NTS](https://www.twilio.com/docs/stun-turn) or [Xirsys TURN Service](https://xirsys.com/).

For better understanding you can also visit this link: [Real-time-Communication-Android](https://github.com/mail2chromium/Android_Realtime_Communication_Using_WebRTC)